# Can't create pdf using python PDFKIT Error : “ OSError: No wkhtmltopdf executable found: "b''": ”

Tags: html, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to get a PDF file from my HTML template using **pdfkit** library and **wkhtmltopdf** but I get an error and I don't find any solutions on Stackoverflow.

my code  sample is along the lines of
ren = render_template('demo.html',name=name,loc=loc)
pdf = pdfkit.from_string(ren,False)

the error :
OSError: No wkhtmltopdf executable found: "b''"
If this file exists please check that this process can read it. Otherwise please install wkhtmltopdf - https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit/wiki/Installing-wkhtmltopdf

I have already installed wkhtmltopdf and changed directories

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me for pdfkit is -

first verify if wkhtmltopdf binary exists, by running

`ls /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf`

if doesn't exist, create it using

`touch /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf`

then after that run the below command which downloads and install wkhtmltopdf

```
wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.3/wkhtmltox-0.12.3_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz && tar vxf wkhtmltox-0.12.3_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz && cp wkhtmltox/bin/wk* /usr/bin/
```

suit your version for download